# Are there functions in PostgreSQL like Oracles 'UPDATING, DELETING, INSERTING' functions?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I hope that someone can help.
Currently I'm working with a PostgreSQL database but I really don't know how I can solve my problem. In PLSQL there are operations inside a trigger called 'INSERTING, UPDATING, DELETING'. But when it comes to PostgreSQL I'm baffered...

In Oracle I can do this:

```
v_action CHAR(1) := CASE WHEN INSERTING THEN "I" WHEN UPDATING THEN "U" WHEN DELETING THEN "D" END;
```

Comment: you are looking for `TG_OP`?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

> TG_OP Data type text; a string of INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or TRUNCATE
>   telling for which operation the trigger was fired.

This should do the trick:

```
v_action := CASE 
  WHEN TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN 'I' 
  WHEN TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN 'U' 
  WHEN TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN 'D' 
END;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I looked for. But when the trigger gets triggered I get following error: `ERROR: column "INSERT" does not exist`

Comment: What it looks like in my trigger: `v_action CHAR(1) := CASE WHEN TG_OP = "INSERT" THEN "I" WHEN TG_OP = "UPDATE" THEN "U" WHEN TG_OP = "DELETE" THEN "D" END;`

Comment: single quotes, not double.